# Chat Board functionality in Iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm looking for away to allow users of my app to chat with each other. Doesn't have to be almost realtime chat say like on an instant messenger. Also i don't want a forum where people write long posts and have topics.

So maybe a chat wall would be an accurate description.

- Users would not be authenticated or anything.
- Only 1 chat wall, no private messaging or any other functionality besides writing to the wall.

I have available to me a pretty basic hosting server where I can throw up some files, it has MySQL DB and php available to me. I dnt know Php, but is there maybe something that php could do to inject messages into the database and maybe it could return all the messages that were added to the database in the last say for sake of argument, a week.

Another method could be to setup a Twitter account and then have users posting to the twitter page and then reading back all the tweets and writing them to the chat wall in the app. It would seem this could be the simplest solution.

What do you guys think? Any ideas of how this could be handled?

Thanks
-Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution might be to create a simple PHP script that writes to a text or HTML file (Google for examples of that...http://tinyurl.com/6ajjt4r). That file could then be read by your app and either parsed or displayed in a UIWebView.